# Fill public strings with Database info from userlogin

Tags: c#

I have created a class that gets the user details from DB to strings (username,userpassword,usernr,usersubco).
What i want to happen is that those strings fill with the info from the user I login with.

```
public class Details
{
    public connectionUser constring = new connectionUser();
    public string Technr;
    public string Techpass;
    public string Techname;
    public string Techsubco;
    public Details()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring.source))
        {
            myInlogForm myI = new myInlogForm();
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from techs where technr=@technr", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"technr", SqlDbType.Int).Value = myI.technr;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Technr = reader[0].ToString();
                Techpass = reader[1].ToString();
                Techname = reader[2].ToString();
                Techsubco = reader[3].ToString();
                break;
            }
            con.Close();

        }
        MessageBox.Show(Techname + Technr + Techpass + Techsubco);
    }
```

`myI = usercontrol (inlogscreen)`
`myIn.technummer` is a public string that get value on loginbutton from textbox.

when I push login I got the message box from this class above (empty) and following error :

UPDATED !!!

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The parameterized query
>   '(@technr int)select * from techs where technr=@technr' expects the
>   parameter '@technr', which was not supplied.'

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> callMenu; // oproep door mainform
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> callDash; // oproep door mainform
    public int technr;

    private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cUser.source.ToString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select technr,techcode from techs where technr=@technr and techcode=@techcode", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"technr",SqlDbType.Int).Value = userTxb.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(@"techcode",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passTxb.Text;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && callMenu != null && callDash != null) // checks login is juist
            {
                callMenu(this, new EventArgs());
                callDash(this, new EventArgs());
                technr = int.Parse(userTxb.Text);             

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Foutieve gegevens");
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems like your SQL Query is incorrect. Try running it directly on the database and see if it still throws an error. And by the way you might want to look into something along the lines of [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070434/using-prepared-statement-in-c-sharp-with-mysql) to avoid SQL Injection

Comment: In some cases schema also needed try this => select * from [schemaName].techs

Comment: if i use "SELECT * FROM techs" it gives me the information of the first user(?query?).

Comment: Make sure your table in db is named `techs` - sometimes simple typo causes to spend much time to find it.

Comment: MindSwipe, changed everything to prepared statements.

Comment: Serhat Oz, stays the same after changes like urs

Comment: Miamy, techs is ok

Comment: Did you try running this Command on the database? Also what DB are you using? P.S you need to do @Username for people to get notifications when you comment ;)

Comment: @MindSwipe i'm using a local service based database for now. In the future it wil be upgraded to a network based database.

Comment: Yes but what kind of SQL are you using? MySQL, sqlite3, MSSQL... ? Also did you try manually connecting to the DB and running the query from there?

Comment: @MindSwipe, `SqlClient.SqlException` comes from MS SQL Server.

Comment: could it be because technr is a numeric char?

Comment: No, this shouldn't be a problem. But did you try to execute this query directly on the Database? If so, did it throw an error aswell?

Comment: @MindSwipe select * from techs where technr= 8368 …  works. Something with the myIn.technr.

Comment: Updated !!. When i change myI.technr to "6650" it works.

Answer (score 1):

try it in this way

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(@"@technr", SqlDbType.Int).Value = myI.technr;
```

Comment: When i change myI.technr to "6650" it works. the public string technr from myI does not get a value i guess